# "Access violation writing location" with file.getline? (Only in release build)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, access-violation

getting this error in an application written in C++ (VS 2010):

> Unhandled exception at 0x77648da9 in divt.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x00000014.

it points to this function in free.c:

```
void __cdecl _free_base (void * pBlock)
{

        int retval = 0;


        if (pBlock == NULL)
            return;

        RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Free_hook, (pBlock, 0));

        retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
        if (retval == 0) //<-----------------------right here
        {
            errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
        }
}
```

Via debugging I was able to determine where its actually crashing:

```
void MenuState::LoadContentFromFile(char* File,std::string &Content)
{
    std::string strbuf;

    char buffer[1028];

    std::fstream file;
    file.open(File,std::ios_base::in);

    if(file.fail()) 
    {
        Content = ErrorTable->GetString("W0001");
        return;
    }
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            file.getline(buffer,128,'\n');  // <----here
            strbuf = buffer;
            Content += strbuf + "\n";
        }
    }

    file.close();

    strbuf.clear();
}
```

It crashes on **file.getline(buffer,128,'\n');**

I don't understand why but it's only doing it in release build (Optimizations turned off), on debug build its working fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You might have a stack overflow, check your stack size. Do you really need the buffer to be 1028, if you only read 128 bytes into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked a friend for help, we came up with this Solution:

```
std::string strbuf;

char buffer[256] = "\0";

FILE* f = fopen(File, "rt");

while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),f) != NULL)
{
    Content += buffer;
}

fclose(f);
strbuf.clear();
```

Works fine, still thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but when you encounter these sorts of issues buried deep in files such as, free.c or xmemory, you may also want to double check your project configuration. Especially when the issue pertains to only certain build configurations.

For example, in MSVC check your Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library. Make sure it consistent for all dependencies and that it is set to a Debug/Release variant depending on the current build.

Comment: This is a great answer. I was strugling with exactly this problem

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that the read **prior** to the read crashing the application actually failed (although I'm not quite sure why it would crash). The important thing to note is that `eof()` is **only** good for determining what caused a read failure (and typically suppressing an error message). In addition, you always want to check **after** the read whether it was successful. Finally, I can't see any reason why you don't read an `std::string` directly. In summary, try to use this loop instead:

```
for (std::string strbuf; std::getline(file, strbuf); ) {
    Content += strbuf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply didnt know of std::getline. I saw that std::fstream::getline wasnt supporting std::string so I found a workaround. But it's still crashing with the same error.

Comment: Hm, not good. How are you calling the function? Is it possible that Content ended up being a stale reference?

Comment: Calling it in the constructor of the class: `LoadContentFromFile("scripts/news.txt",NewsContent);` NewsContent is an `std::string`.

Comment: If the string is properly constructed this code doesn't seem to be the problem... I would settle with having to run the code with something like purify or valgrind to see what this has to say about it. That is, first I would try with a clean slate and rebuild everything to see if this changes anything...

Comment: Okay i've checked it with purify and a few other programms with no results. It crashes everytime I try to read an file. On other functions too with the same Error, even the same adress location: `0x00000014.` Not sure if it helps but some data about the `std::string Newscontent` : `Capacity: 15 | MaxSize: -2 | Size: 0`